# Forward example.com website to www.example.com

Tags: domain-name-system

I am trying to point `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

Because searching `https://www.example.com` loads the website with no issues, but searching `https://example.com` leads to an extremely long load time and then it just crashes to the screen where it says "website cannot be loaded / check proxy and firewall etc.

Is this an issue with the way the DNS has been setup? I set up 301 forwarding as well many days back but still having the same issues today.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! In your questions please refrain from using random domain names and use either your *own domain* or one of the [RFC 6761](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761#section-6.5) reserved domain names such as  `example.com`, `example.org`  or similar . Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

Comment: I might help if you include how your dns zone is currently configured(anonymous). You can use digwebinterface.com for that

Comment: Ot use `dig ANY +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats www.google.com. google.com. @4.2.2.2 ` Where you replace google.com with your domain

Answer (score 2):

DNS can't forward, it can only alias (via *CNAME*). If you want forward, that's on your web server.

So, point *`example.com`* to your web server, using an A record (same IP address as *`www.example.com`* or a totally different server) and then configure the web server to forward from the bare domain to www.

As @Zdenek has reminded me, you can't put a CNAME on a bare domain.

Comment: A naked domain.com can never be CNAME, it's stuck with a direct IP specification via A/AAAA records. It's because historically, CNAME has to be the only record while the naked domain requires other records, more here: https://serverfault.com/questions/576130/using-a-cname-to-forward-traffic-from-a-naked-domain

Comment: @Zdenek Absolutely - what was I thinking?...

Comment: And to state the (not always for everyone) obvious redirecting HTTPS  URL's requires valid certificates that include all domain names

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this could be an issue with your DNS setup.

The habitual practise is set up the root domain as `A` type record, and the www as a `CNAME` type record pointing to @ or root domain.

If you have set up 301 redirect, ensure they are configured from `example.com` to `www.example.com` (subdomain) if you want to use www as default domain.

Also from the server side, check if you're using the `.htaccess` file to redirect requests from `example.com` to `www.example.com` in case to use Apache, a properly server block configuration for Nginx webserver.

Comment: And to state the (not always for everyone) obvious : redirecting HTTPS URL's requires valid certificates for all used domain names, so for both `example.com` and `www.example.com`

Comment: "set up the root domain as A type record, and the www as a CNAME type record pointing to @ or root domain" - might be habitual for you, but it is BAD practice. As per discussion elsewhere the apex/bare/null DNS records have specific rules which restrict what you can do with them. Working with multiple hosts, geo-aware DNS, 3rd party CDNs becomes a lot more difficult. The www. record should be the canonical hostname and the webserver at the apex should redirect there.

Comment: @symcbean You can use www. as the canonical address for the website and still CNAME it to the base domain in the DNS. One has nothing to do with the other and it is not bad practise.

Comment: "Working with multiple hosts, geo-aware DNS, 3rd party CDNs becomes a lot more difficult."